# Vite/Vue3/Typescript VueUse: onClickOutside problem

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, vueuse

I use Vue3 w/Vite and Typescript and would like to implememnt the VueUse onClickOutside composable something like this (a simplified code):

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div
            @click="isShow = !isShow"
            ref="ignoreElRef"
        >
            <div
                v-if="isShow"
                v-on-click-outside="onClickOutsideHandler"
            >
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref, Ref } from 'vue'
import { vOnClickOutside } from '@vueuse/components'

//handle toggle
const isShow = ref(false)

const ignoreElRef: Ref<HTMLElement | null> = ref(null)
const onClickOutsideHandler = [
    () => {
        isShow.value = false
    },
    {
        ignore: [ignoreElRef],
    },
]

</script>
```

I got the following error message:

```
Argument of type '((() => void) | { ignore: Ref<HTMLElement | null>[]; })[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OnClickOutsideHandler<{ detectIframe: false; }> | [(evt: any) => void, OnClickOutsideOptions]'.
  Type '((() => void) | { ignore: Ref<HTMLElement | null>[]; })[]' is not assignable to type 'OnClickOutsideHandler<{ detectIframe: false; }>'.ts(2345)
```

How should I rewrite the onClickOutsideHandler function to fix this issue? I tried in several way but there is no solution found.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Your handler should be a function, then the type for it would be `OnClickOutsideHandler` imported from `@vueuse/core`

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref, Ref } from 'vue'
import { vOnClickOutside } from '@vueuse/components'
import type { OnClickOutsideHandler } from '@vueuse/core'

//handle toggle
const isShow = ref(false)

const ignoreElRef: Ref<HTMLElement | null> = ref(null)
const onClickOutsideHandler: OnClickOutsideHandler = () => {
  isShow.value = false
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, the TS error message disappeared successfully. In this case, however, the toggle doesn't work properly. The ignoreElRef doesn't call anytime. In simple javascript the above mentioned code snippet works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

A solution

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref, Ref } from 'vue'
import { vOnClickOutside } from '@vueuse/components'
import type { OnClickOutsideOptions } from '@vueuse/core'


// handle toggle
const isShow = ref(false)

const ignoreElRef: Ref<HTMLElement | null> = ref(null)
const onClickOutsideHandler: [(evt: any) => void, OnClickOutsideOptions] = [
    (evt: any) => {
        isShow.value = false
    },
    {
        ignore: [ignoreElRef],
    },
]

</script>
```